# DAX dates between if statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in dax and trying to create a calculated column in a calendar table for which I want values to be returned in a new column 1 or 0 based if the CalendarDate is in the period.
I tried the following which returns the correct values but I need to change after "&&" that it returns the dates  - 2 month from last sales date.

```
"Last 2 periods"; If ([Date]<=LASTDATE(Sales[SalesDate]) 
&& [Date]> DATE(2019;10;02);1;0);
```

I tried following but this does not work:

```
"Last 2 periods"; If ([Date]<=LASTDATE(Sales[SalesDate]) 
&& [Date]> DATEADD(LASTDATE(Sales[SalesDate]);-2;MONTH);1;0);
```

Any suggestions? Or proposals for the best way to create this column in DAX?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the max function instead of last date. The sample calculation would look like below:

```
Last 2 Periods = IF(Sales[Date]<=MAX(Sales[SalesDate])&&DATEADD(Sales[Date].[Date],2,MONTH)>max(Sales[SalesDate]),1,0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this proposal was not fixing the issue. I get following message "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."